# How to mass archive articles in Apex?

Tags: apex, knowledge

I am trying to mass archive articles but entering the below in the developer console returns: Method does not exist or incorrect signature KbManagement.PublishingService.archiveOnlineArticle(LIST,NULL).

My guess is that this method doesn't accept a LIST only a single Id, in that case how can I mass archive those articles?

```
List<Documentation__kav> toDelete=new List<Documentation__kav>([Select Id, KnowledgeArticleId
     FROM Documentation__kav WHERE ImportId__c='' AND Language='en_US' AND PublishStatus='Online']);

List<Id> archiveArticles=new List<Id>();

for (Documentation__kav kav:toDelete)
{
    archiveArticles.add(kav.KnowledgeArticleId);

}

List<KnowledgeArticle> archived=new List <KnowledgeArticle>([Select Id from KnowledgeArticle WHERE ID=:archiveArticles]);

KbManagement.PublishingService.archiveOnlineArticle(archived,null)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try performing the archive in a batch.

**Disclaimer: I put this together directly here to outline the idea. It may not compile or run as expected.**

```
global class ArchiveArticles implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    global string query;

    global ArchiveArticles() {
        query = 'Select Id, KnowledgeArticleId FROM Documentation__kav WHERE ImportId__c=\'\' AND Language=\'en_US\' AND PublishStatus=\'Online\'';
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
         return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> toDelete) {
        for (Documentation__kav kav:toDelete)
        {
            KbManagement.PublishingService.archiveOnlineArticle(kav.knowledgeArticleId,null);
        }    
    }

}
```

When starting adjust the batch size to stay within the governor limits.

```
// Adjust this batch size as required.
integer batchSize = 25;
ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(new ArchiveArticles(), batchSize);
```

Comment: I am accepting this as a solution as it compiled and seems like a good option, unfortunately it returned an internal server error when executed, probably a bug.

Comment: @Daniel Can you please help with the question here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309951/bulk-update-throws-only-draft-articles-can-be-update-publication-status where I am updating the knowledge article through data loader but gettting Only draft articles can be update : Publication Status error

Answer (score 1):

I think KbManagement.PublishingService class does not allow us to operate in bulk. It accepts a single Id. Moreover if you keep this operation in a for loop like :

```
for (Documentation__kav kav:toDelete)
{
    KbManagement.PublishingService.archiveOnlineArticle(kav.knowledgeArticleId,null);

}
```

you are likely to hit the DML limits exception "Too many DML statements: 151"

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing that as an extreme measure but even that failed with something like "The operation is not allowed...." Thanks!

Comment: You are trying this operation on a published article right ? I was able to archive a published article with " KbManagement.PublishingService.archiveOnlineArticle(kav.knowledgeArticleId,null)"

Comment: I can do that as well but not when inside a loop. Maybe I did something wrong, anyway, that wouldn't be a solution :(

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing below error for me.

FATAL_ERROR System.HandledException: You can't perform this action. Be sure the action is valid for the current state of the article, and that you have permission to perform it.

I have checked all Object Permissions and System permissions for Knowledge Article, I have System Admin access.

Can Anyone help here?

Comment: Rather than asking a question in an answer space, please ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). In your new question you can link to this question for reference if you like. (Please note that this "answer" will most likely be deleted. *See information in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)*)